# Is there a code for the Run button using Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am doing mini project.

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Runcode();

}
```

I am currently stuck here. what code should I add so that the codes from the textbox will run after clicking this button?